# Validate Input box entry between min and max number

Tags: excel, vba

I used `InputBox` for the "period" which is the month ("m").

When I try using it for the "year" ("YYYY") it does not function as expected.

My code for the "year" (same as in "period", only different values and variables):

```
Dim VYear as variant
Dim defY as variant

defY = Format(DateAdd("YYYY", 0, Now), "YYYY")
VYear = InputBox("Year covered","Year",defY)
If VYear > 2014 And VYear < defY Then
    Range("I1").Value = VYear
ElseIf VYear = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Do Until VYear > 2014 And VYear < defY
    MsgBox "Please enter a year not earlier than 2015 and not later than this year"
    VYear = InputBox("Year covered")
    Loop
End If
```

It does give me the default value of 2018. When I tried entering wrong values, it proceeds with the message in `MsgBox` as expected, but it would no longer accept ANY values, even the year "2018".

Cycle goes: `MsgBox` (Please enter....) then `InputBox` then `MsgBox` again.

I intentionally used `As Variant` so that even though users input letters, it won't give the error of *"type mismatch"*.

Answer (score 2):

It should look like this …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AskForYear()
    Dim InputValue As Variant   'needs to be variant because input is FALSE if cancel button is pressed
    Dim DefaultYear As Integer

    DefaultYear = Year(Date)    'Get the year of the current date today

    Do
        InputValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a Year between 2015 and " & DefaultYear & "." & vbCrLf & "Year covered:", Title:="Year", Default:=DefaultYear, Type:=1)
        If VarType(InputValue) = vbBoolean And InputValue = False Then Exit Sub  'cancel was pressed
    Loop While InputValue < 2015 Or InputValue > DefaultYear

    Range("I1").Value = InputValue 'write input value
End Sub
```

- It uses a `Do` loop that is at least run once (note the criteria is in the `Loop While` part). It keeps asking for a date between 2015 and this year until the criteria is met. Then it will continue to write into the range.
- Note that there is a cancel criteria to catch if the user pressed the cancel button. Then it exits the sub without writing into the range.

  > ***This is just hypothetical for your specific case (asking for a year) but …***
  >   For this criteria it is not sufficient to test `If InputValue = False` if you plan to accept `0` as number input. Therefore you need also to test for `Boolean`type:
  >   `If VarType(InputValue) = vbBoolean`
  >   This is because `False` is automatically cast to `0`.
- Note that I used `Application.InputBox` instead of `InputBox`. These are 2 completely different ones:

  ```
  Application.InputBox(Prompt, Title, Default, Left, Top, HelpFile, HelpContextID, Type)
  'see the different parameters
  InputBox(Prompt, Title, Default, XPos, YPos, HelpFile, Context) As String
  ```

  In `Application.InputBox` you can provide a `Type` parameter which I set to `1` which means it only accepts numbers (see [Application.InputBox Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox#remarks)). With just `InputBox` you cannot do this.
- I recommend to use meaningful variable names, which makes it much easier to read and maintain the code. Also only use `Variant` if really necessary. In this case it is, because the `Application.InputBox` can either return a `Boolean` (cancel button) or number (input).
- Another recommendation is to *always* specify a worksheet for a `Range` like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1")` otherwise Excel guesses which worksheet you mean and it might easily fail.

Comment: A full reply and instructive for many readers to learn about `Application.InputBox` +1)